# Automatically replace the first & with a ? question mark

Tags: codeigniter

I have this code below which generates a query string for my url.

Question I would like to know is there away that it could automatically replace the first `&` with a `?` question mark no matter what the first $_GET is.

```
$url = '';

if ($this->input->get('directory')) {
   $pos = strrpos($this->input->get('directory'), '/');

   if ($pos) {
      $url .= '&directory=' . urlencode(substr($this->input->get('directory'), 0, $pos));
   }
}

if ($this->input->get('target')) {
    $url .= '&target=' . $this->input->get('target'); 
}

if ($this->input->get('thumb')) {
    $url .= '&thumb=' . $this->input->get('thumb'); 
} 


$data['parent'] = base_url('image_manager' . $url);
```

Comment: from where you need to replace the first `&` with a `?`. Example:  `$s = 'Automatically replace the first & with a ? question mark';
if (strpos($s,'&')) {
 $s = str_replace('&', '?', $s);
}
echo $s;`

Comment: The if there is `get('directory');` then that should be the first one with '?' if not the next one would be `get('target')`

Comment: do you need to get `$url` like `?directory=xxx&target=xxx&thumb=xxx`

Comment: Use [http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

Answer (score 0):

Found solution

```
$find = '&';
$replace = '?';

$result = preg_replace("/$find/", $replace, $url, 1);

echo $result;
```